# I need to delete login user details when submit a delete button,how can i do that in jsp

Tags: jsp

I  need to delete login user details when submit a delete button,how can i do that in jsp

here is my Loginuser.jsp:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">



<script src="../scripts/login.js"></script>


 <body >
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <title>E Bank</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css\loginstudent.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


  </head>
  </head>
  <body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="Home.jsp">E Bank</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="Home.jsp">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="Loginuser.jsp"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-education"></span> Login</a> 
 </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  </nav>
  <div class = "pageBody">


  <div id ="loginForm">
    <div class = "loginform-back" >
        <label style="color: #2439AD" id="signInfont"> <b> Sign In <br> </b></label>
        <label style="color: #14A57C"><b><br> </b></label>
        <br><br>
        <form method="post" action="login.jsp">   <!-- -------------------------- login form begin -- 
 >
            <table width="100%">

                <tr>
                    <td>User Name</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="uname" value="" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password</td>
                    <td><input type="password" name="pass" value="" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>

                    <td><input type="submit" value="Login" /></td>
                    <td><p>Not registered</p><a href="signupuser.jsp" style = "text-decoration : 
none;  margin-top : 2px ; color : gray ; font-size : 15px;"><br>Create and Account</a>


                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>  <!-- ----------------------------- end of the form -->
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
<footer class="container-fluid text-center">
<p>Developed By #Himantha #Buddhima #Amindi #Gayath</p>
</footer>

</body>

</body>
</html>
```

here is login.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
<%
String userid = request.getParameter("uname");
String pwd = request.getParameter("pass");
Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ebank? 
user=root&password=Gayya");
Statement st = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs;
`enter code here`rs = st.executeQuery("select * from members where uname='" + userid + "' and pass='" 
+ pwd + "'");
if (rs.next()) {
    session.setAttribute("uname", userid);
    //out.println("welcome " + userid);
    //out.println("<a href='logout.jsp'>Log out</a>");
    response.sendRedirect("useraccount.jsp");
} else {
    out.println("Invalid password <a href='Loginuser.jsp'>try again</a>");
}
%>
```

here is useraccount.jsp

```
<%@ page import="com.mysql.jdbc.Connection" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.DriverManager" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.Statement" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.ResultSet" %><%--
Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
User: Gayath
Date: 4/17/2020
Time: 2:03 AM
To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
--%>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
<title>Dashboard - E bank</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css? 
 h=5cf6485885415ba67d4e9cefe93072c6">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.12.0/css/all.css">
</head>

 <body id="page-top">
 <div id="wrapper">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark align-items-start sidebar sidebar-dark accordion bg-gradient-primary 
 p-0">
    <div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column p-0">
        <a class="navbar-brand d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center sidebar-brand m-0" 
 href="#">
            <div class="sidebar-brand-icon rotate-n-15"><i class="fas fa-laugh-wink"></i></div>
            <div class="sidebar-brand-text mx-3"><span>E Bank</span></div>
        </a>
        <hr class="sidebar-divider my-0">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav text-light" id="accordionSidebar">
            <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link" href="update.jsp"><i 
 class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i><span>Update Profile details</span></a></li>
            <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link" href="Loginuser.jsp"><i 
 class="fas fa-user-circle"></i><span>Log Out</span></a></li>
            <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link" href="delete.jsp"><i 
  class="fas fa-user-circle"></i><span>Delete account</span></a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="text-center d-none d-md-inline"></div>
    </div>
 </nav>
 <div class="d-flex flex-column" id="content-wrapper">
    <div id="content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="d-sm-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-4">
                <h3 class="text-dark mb-0">Dashboard</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-3 mb-4">
                    <div class="card shadow border-left-primary py-2">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="row align-items-center no-gutters">
                                <div class="col mr-2">
                                    <div class="text-uppercase text-primary font-weight-bold text-xs 
  mb-1"><span>Balance</span></div>
                                    <div class="text-dark font-weight-bold h5 mb-0"><a class="nav- 
 link" href="balance.jsp"><button><span>Balance</span></button></a></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-auto"><i class="fas fa-calendar fa-2x text-gray-300"> 
 </i></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-3 mb-4">
                    <div class="card shadow border-left-success py-2">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="row align-items-center no-gutters">
                                <div class="col mr-2">
                                    <div class="text-uppercase text-success font-weight-bold text-xs 
  mb-1"><button><span>Online payment</span></button></div>

                                </div>
                                <div class="col-auto"><i class="fas fa-dollar-sign fa-2x text-gray- 
 300"></i></div>
                             </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="bg-white sticky-footer">
        <div class="container my-auto">
            <div class="text-center my-auto copyright"><span>Copyright © Ebank2020</span></div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter- 
bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.4.1/jquery.easing.js"></script>
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/assets/js/script.min.js? 
h=9af5f655239f5ce4fa692ca1c1513d50"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

here is delete.jsp

```
 <%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
 <%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
 <%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>

<%
String userid = request.getParameter("uname");
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ebank","root","Gayya");
Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
stat.executeUpdate("delete from members where uname ='test'");
response.sendRedirect("Home.jsp");
%>
```

i can delete specific name when giving the value of a row but i need delete the current loginuser details.can anyone help me with this?thank you

Comment: does your current login user is store in `session` ? if yes , why don't you get it from session and passed the same in your `delete` query .

Comment: problem sloved!thank you